# If mean absolute loss is not differentiable, how it can be used in neural networks? which majorly are trained using back-propagation

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, regression, loss-function, backpropagation

If Mean Absolute Error (MAE) loss is not differentiable, how can it be used in neural networks? which majorly are trained using back-propagation

I am wondering if MAE is not differentiable how they can be used as a loss function.

Comment: MAE is differentiable. Refer to this link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312737/mean-absolute-error-mae-derivative

Comment: So basically MAE is not differentiable at 0 and attaining 0 loss is ideal(in which case we can stop optimization). in all other conditions, MAE is differentiable.

Comment: Yes it is differentiatable at all values of y_pred except when y_pred is equal to y_true. And I would assume there are very few instances where y_pred is exactly equal to y_true.

Answer (score 2):

Mean Absolute Error (MAE) is differentiable at all points expect when predicted target value equals true target value. It is relatively rare for predicted target value equals true target value and software implementations have conditional logic that handles that edge case.